# Solr: tokenize/search parts of domain name

Tags: solr

**Requirement**

One of my text fields contains (among other things) domain names. Given (e.g.) the text "www.docs.corp.com", I would like to be able to search for "www", "docs", "corp", "com", "www.docs", "docs.corp", "corp.com", "www.docs.corp", "docs.corp.com", or "www.docs.corp.com", and find the relevant document containing "www.docs.corp.com".

**What I currently do:**

Currently I use a charFilter to change "." to space before tokenizing with `StandardTokenizerFactory`:

```
<fieldType name="text_clr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([.])" replacement=" "/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([.])" replacement=" "/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This kind-of works, but when looking for "corp.com" will actually look for "corp com", and will thus find some unrelated matches, such as "... corp. com.company.www will also ..." and of course many other false positives.

**Hypothesis**

What I *think* I need is a token filter: something that will take the token "www.docs.corp.com" and produce multiple tokens from it: ["www", "docs", "corp", "com", "www.docs", "docs.corp", "corp.com", "www.docs.corp", "docs.corp.com", "www.docs.corp.com"].

**Question**

Is this the right approach, or am I missing something elegant, like an existing filter than I can configure to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, for the sake of those who might look for something like in the future.

It appears as though my proposed solution is indeed the way to go. I have gone ahead and implemented it, and am posting it here. It is comprised of 2 classes: a Token Filter and a Token-Filter-Factory. Usage should be obvious for anyone verse in Solr.

A link to a quick write-up I did for this: http://blog.nitzanshaked.net/solr-domain-name-tokenizer/

The files:

**DomainNameTokenFilterFactory.java**

```
package com.clarityray.solr.analysis;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory;
import com.clarityray.solr.analysis.DomainNameTokenFilter;

public class DomainNameTokenFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory {

    private int minLen;
    private int maxLen;
    private boolean withOriginal;

    public DomainNameTokenFilterFactory(Map<String,String> args) {
        super(args);
        withOriginal = getBoolean(args, "withOriginal", true);
        minLen = getInt(args, "minLen", 2);
        maxLen = getInt(args, "maxLen", -1);
        if (!args.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown parameters: " + args);
    }

    @Override
    public TokenStream create(TokenStream ts) {
        return new DomainNameTokenFilter(ts, minLen, maxLen, withOriginal);
    }

}
```

**DomainNameTokenFilter.java**

```
package com.clarityray.solr.analysis;

import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionIncrementAttribute;

public class DomainNameTokenFilter extends TokenFilter {

    private CharTermAttribute charTermAttr;
    private PositionIncrementAttribute posIncAttr;
    private Queue<String> output;
    private int nextPositionIncrement;

    private int minLen;
    private int maxLen;
    private boolean withOriginal;

    public DomainNameTokenFilter(TokenStream ts, int minLen, int maxLen, boolean withOriginal) {
        super(ts);
        this.charTermAttr = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        this.posIncAttr = addAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class);
        this.output = new LinkedList<String>();
        this.minLen = minLen;
        this.maxLen = maxLen;
        this.withOriginal = withOriginal;
    }

    private String join(String glue, String[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (end < start)
            return "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(arr[start]);
        for (int i = start+1; i <= end; ++i) {
            sb.append(glue);
            sb.append(arr[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {

        // first -- output and ready tokens
        if (!output.isEmpty()) {
            charTermAttr.setEmpty();
            charTermAttr.append(output.poll());
            posIncAttr.setPositionIncrement(0);
            return true;
        }

        // no tokens ready in output buffer? get next token from input stream
        if (!input.incrementToken())
            return false;

        // get the text for the current token
        String s = charTermAttr.toString();

        // if the input does not look like a domain name, we leave it as is
        if (s.indexOf('.') == -1)
            return true;

        // create all sub-sequences
        String[] subParts = s.split("[.]");
        int actualMaxLen = Math.min(
            this.maxLen > 0 ? this.maxLen : subParts.length,
            subParts.length
        );
        for (int currentLen = this.minLen; currentLen <= actualMaxLen; ++currentLen)
            for (int i = 0; i + currentLen - 1 < subParts.length; ++i)
                output.add(join(".", subParts, i, i + currentLen - 1));

        // preserve original if so asked
        if (withOriginal && actualMaxLen < subParts.length)
            output.add(s);

        // output first of the generated tokens
        charTermAttr.setEmpty();
        charTermAttr.append(output.poll());
        posIncAttr.setPositionIncrement(1);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I like your solution, but it still seems like this should be possible using Solr's built-in filters..

Answer (score 0):

I would add the WordDelimiterFilterFactory with the preserveOriginal option in combination with the WhitespaceTokenizerFactory

> preserveOriginal="1" causes the original token to be indexed without
>   modifications (in addition to the tokens produced due to other
>   options)
>
> ```
> default is 0
> ```

The WhitespaceTokenizerFactory will leave the periods in place. When you then use the WordDelimiterFilterFactory with the preserveOriginal option it should index both the component parts and the original. I'd also consider adding LowerCaseFilterFactory otherwise you may get mixed case into your index which is probably not what you are looking for.

So something like this although you'll need to play with it a bit:

```
<fieldType name="text_clr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This may not get you all the way there but it should give you a good start. I'd take a look at this page for more details on the WordDelimiterFilterFactory:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

Comment: I've considered this, but this will not help me with "www.google", for example, right?

Comment: No, for that use case I'd try wild cards

Comment: How exactly will I use wildcards for this? Will this be reasonable performance?

Comment: I think for trailing edge wildcards performance should be fine, like www.google* . If you want to perform leading edge wildcards I'd look at  ReversedWildcardFilterFactory as it substantially improves performance for leading edge wild card queries.

Comment: 4 part web site addresses weren't in your question - I'd add it and other use cases that you need covered. Other than some custom coding I can't see how you're going to do this with standard tokenizers and filters/

Comment: Good comment, I'll add to the use cases, thanks. As for custom coding: that was exactly my original question: would you say that my proposed solution is the way, or am I missing something elegant?

Comment: Yes probably although I'd also take a look at solr.ShingleFilterFactory. It takes a token stream and creates a token ngram (a shingle) out of the tokens. So after you've tokenized on period and produced www google com it could also produce tokens like "www google" and "google com" which could then replace the whitespace with a period. Still problably not good enough, but should give you some ideas of how to make modifications to any of the tokenizers and filter we've discussed to output exactly what you are looking for.